# How to access WordPress dashboard and cPanel

Tags: html, asp.net

I am in the process of setting up a WordPress website. I paid for hosting and a domain name and the website opened with "Hello World" and that is all. I cannot lo into it, I cannot access the dashboard, I cannot access the cPanel. What should I do? I am a total newbie.

Comment: Who is your host?  They should include setup instructions to guide you through the process.

Comment: Contact your hosting provider and check your email. But for now you can go to http://example.com/wp-admin and try to reset your password using your email.

Answer (score 0):

did you check .htaccess file if exist or not?

If .htaccess doesnt exist please create one and put codes below, save and upload to your server.